# finding solution to $au_x+bu_y=f(x,y)$ where $a \neq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I can't get the solution in the required form of $$u(x,y)=(a^2+b^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int_{L}fds +g(bx-ay)$$

"where g is an arbitrary function of one variable, L is the characteristic
line segment from the y axis to the point (x, y), and the integral is a line
integral." 
Example from a book Strauss PDE (Exercise 1.11 p 9.)

Ma attempt: 
using the coordinate method with
$$\xi=bx-ay$$
$$\nu=ax+by$$

I get the following equation
$$u_{\nu}=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2} \ \ f(\nu,\xi)$$
integrating both sides with respect to $\nu$ I get
$$u=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2} \big{(} \int f(\nu,\xi) d\nu + g(\xi) \big{)}$$
$$u=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2} \big{(} \int f(\nu,\xi) d\nu + g(bx-ay) \big{)}$$

**I don't understand how can it be transitioned into the required solution form from this point on?**

Comment: Can you say what $L$ is?